# Autocomplete a textbox which is populated from an xml file (vb.net)

Tags: xml, vb.net, autocomplete, textbox

I'm trying to auto fill a textbox populated from an xml file however I cant get the dataset part right...

```
Dim ds As New DataSet()
ds.ReadXml("C:\hello.xml")
Dim datacollection As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
   For i As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
       datacollection.Add(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(1).ToString)
   Next

   TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
   TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.append
   TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = datacollection
```

Comment: This is an unclear - please have a look at [ask] and give more detail. Errors, expected behaviour and actual behaviour. Thanks :-)

Comment: In a nutshell Ive got a textbox and want to populate its autosugest funtionality with the contents of an xml file Im having trouble reading the dataset again no error caught just no response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using AutoCompleteStringCollection.

```
Dim autocompleteList As New System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteStringCollection
Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader("C:\Hello.xml")
    While Not reader.EndOfStream
        autocompleteList.Add(reader.ReadLine())
    End While
End Using

Me.TextBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
Me.TextBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
Me.TextBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autocompleteList
```

Comment: This works however not for an xml- tag environment... I can use it for now (as txt) so i'll accept your solution... thanks

Comment: I tested with an xml and it worked. What's your error?

Comment: @JustinWoodmancy If the XML file just contains lines of text, ie `123456` `456789` it will start to populate. However if the XML file is properly structured, you need to start typing with a `<` for the autocomplete to start.